# Skew adjoint operator with uncountable spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. I just want an example of a skew adjoint operator $(A^*=-A)$ with **uncountable** spectrum.

I also want an example for unbounded differential operators. The only example I know is the Laplace operator $A=i \Delta$ in the Hilbert space $H=L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with domain $D(A)=H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which is skew adjoint (because $\Delta$ is self adjoint), but $A$ has a countable spectrum.

Comment: Why do you think the spectrum of A is countable? I believe it is the negative imaginary axis.

Comment: Alternatively you could consider multiplication operators (and thanks to the spectral theorem that is all you need to consider). See also my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/779087/822

Comment: @NateEldredge I thought it is discrete, but I just realized it is discrete only in bounded domains as in the link you provided.