# Do we have eigenfunctions for Laplacian in $\Bbb{R}^n$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, eigenfunctions

Does there exist $u\in H^2(\Bbb{R}^n)$ so that $-\Delta u=\lambda u$.

Of course if such $u$ exists, it must be a smooth function by elliptic estimate and bootstrap strategy. So we need to find $u$ so that $-\Delta u=\lambda u$ in classical sense with norm constrain.

I don't think such an eigenfunction exist, but I can't prove it.

Thanks for advance for anyone who could offer help.

Comment: What is $H^2$ here? A Hardy space?

Comment: Sobolev space. $W^{2,2}$

Comment: The free Laplacian has purely continuous spectrum?

Comment: I think that should be the case. But I just have no clue how to prove that.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766479/what-is-spectrum-for-laplacian-in-mathbbrn

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much!