# Positivity of a Sturm-Liouville operator

Tags: spectral-theory, sturm-liouville

Upon reading the link on the [spectrum of the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766479/what-is-spectrum-for-laplacian-in-mathbbrn?rq=1%3E)
I thought of considering a slight generalization:

Let $p$ be a positive function such that $\frac{1}{p} \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$. Consider the Sturm-Liouville operator $L_pu = -(pu')'$ on $\mathbb{R}$. For simplicity, suppose $L_p$ is in the limit point case at $\pm \infty$ so that $L_p$ defined on its maximal domain
$$\{u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) : u,pu' \in AC_{loc}(\mathbb{R}), L_pu \in L^2(\mathbb{R})\}$$
is self-adjoint.

Question: Is $L_p$ a positive operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u \in \mathcal{D}(L)$. Then
$$
     \langle Lu,u\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-(pu')'udx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} pu'u'dx \ge 0.
$$
The reason this works is that $p \ge 0$, and $L$ is in the limit-point case at $\pm\infty$, which guarantees that the evaluation terms vanish at $\infty$.